# Stop the recursion completely when returning something

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

I do recursion to find a long value within a List with multiple children that also can have children.

following method:

```
public TaxonomyData getTaxonomyData(long taxId, List<TaxonomyData> TaxonomyTree, TaxonomyData output)
{
    //find taxid in the taxonomy tree list and return the taxonomydata

    foreach (TaxonomyData td in TaxonomyTree)
    {
        if (td.TaxonomyId == taxId)
        {
                output = td;
                //return td; => when doing a return here means I already found a match so it is not necessary to do all the recursion.
        }
        else if (td.Taxonomy.Length > 0)
        {
            getTaxonomyData(taxId, td.Taxonomy.ToList(), output);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is it possible when I do `return td;` (see commented row) that my whole recursion stops?

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, it will happen. The recursion will stop there.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about stopping the recursive calls to getTaxonomyData? If you are trying to avoid looping innecesarily with the foreach because you already have the value you need then what you have to do is add "break;" right after the "output = td;" instruction. And I think in this case a while would be a better solution...

Comment: @Jani: No, recursion *won't* stop if a deep call just returns - because the recursion would be from the `else` clause, which ignores the return value, and just keeps going with the next element of `TaxonomyTree`.

Comment: Thanks for asking @Ozkan it was missing  `else` for me and I were getting the result for end of tree. BTW, @Jon Skeet I feel in debt to you, as always.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
public TaxonomyData GetTaxonomyData(long taxId, IEnumerable<TaxonomyData> tree)
{
    foreach (TaxonomyData td in tree)
    {
        if (td.TaxonomyId == taxId)
        {
            return td;
        }
        else
        {
            // See if it's in the subtree of td
            TaxonomyData data = GetTaxonomyData(taxId, td.Taxonomy);
            if (data != null)
            {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
    // Haven't found it anywhere in this tree
    return null;
}
```

Each `return` only returns one level, but by checking the return value in the `else` clause, we can return all the way up the stack when we find the right value.

The final result returned to the caller will be a null reference if it hasn't been found.

Note that I've removed the "output" parameter, which wouldn't have been effective anyway as it wasn't a `ref` parameter, and isn't as clear as *just* using the return value.

Comment: That just saves one call. and it's unnecessary IMHO.

Comment: I think tail recursion is the solution

Comment: @Jani: I'm not sure what you mean. The original code simply wouldn't work - it's not using the result of the recursive call at all.

Comment: @Jani: I look forward to seeing your answer - I'm pretty sure my code would work, and do so simply.

Comment: Yes sorry, he missed the return statement in recursive call.

Comment: @Jani: But you can't *just* unconditionally return - you have to see whether the recursive call actually found the desired result in the subtree handled by that particular iteration. Do you still think my code could be simplified?

Comment: And if you unconditionally return, in the next call it will be stopped.

Comment: @Jani: I don't know what you mean by that - or indeed where you mean. But a `return` statement doesn't *automatically* go all the way up the stack (in the way that an uncaught exception does, for example). Again, if you think you've got a simpler solution, please post it.

Comment: Thanks John, Your solution works fine and is faster than mine

Answer (score 1):

A linq extension solution i came up with, probably slower but there you go..

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T SingleOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,Func<T,bool> predicate, Func<T,T> defaultSelector)
        where T : class
    {   
        return enumerable.SingleOrDefault(predicate) ?? enumerable.SkipWhile<T>(t=>defaultSelector(t) == null).Select(defaultSelector).SingleOrDefault();
    } 

    public static TaxonomyData Get(this IEnumerable<TaxonomyData> tree, int taxId)
    {
        return tree.SingleOrDefault(t=> t.TaxonomyId == taxId,t=>t.Taxonomy.Get(taxId));
    }
}
```